# Format bug: edit → mark a text → click on **B** for bold or *I* for italic → start of the format change is slightly too late

Tags: support, bug, formatting

If you click on edit, then mark a word, a line or multiple lines of text, then change the format e.g. to bold, the very first formatting change has a bug.

Reproducible example at least at my laptop using

> Microsoft Edge 44.18362.449.0 with Microsoft EdgeHTML 18.18363, Windows 10 Home Version 1909, 32bit:

- Edit whatever post you have at hand. You might take the [formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox) or any other post and click on edit - please mind that you do not need to save the edit to reproduce the bug, it can be seen directly in the editor.
- Mark just a word, or longer text, e.g. mark "sandbox" in the sandbox' example text "You can use this question as a formatting sandbox. You can:".
- Press on the bold or italic format button or on "block quote" button, with bold you would be expecting to see in the editor (small remark: the stars need to be escaped like \*\*sandbox\*\* so that you can see them here "in edit mode"):

> **sandbox**.

- Find that the format change is shifted to the right, in the example it becomes

> You can use this question as a formatting sandbox. Y**ou can:**

- Once the bug has occurred, it does not reappear again in that edit session, no matter whether you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> after the bug or not.

**Edited:** The same bug also appears when you paste a picture, it will also be shifted.
I have opened a new question that is only about pasting a picture, but the issue should be exactly the same. See [Edit whatever, paste a picture somewhere, and it will be inserted slightly too late](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399646/edit-whatever-paste-a-picture-somewhere-and-it-will-be-inserted-slightly-too-l/399647#399647) for details.

*The new and plausible idea which accounts for both format changes and pasting:*

The shift could be explained with the number of empty lines that are before your current start position.

In the edit mode, you often see 3 lines in a row that are empty, which are then shown as just one empty line in the end. This is the sort of editing which you need to create an empty line in the output. And it seems that the shift of formatting or pasting is linked to those empty lines *before* the start of your action, be it the formatting start or the pasting position of an object.

Example:

- If you paste a picture at the 5th empty line (of all 3-empty-line-blocks only!) in the edited text, it will be shifted by 4 characters or lines (depends on what you have next).
- If you paste a picture at the 6th empty line in the edited text, it will be shifted by 5 characters.
- I have checked this in about 10 cases, the linkage is right on the point.
- If you did the same at the 21th empty line of the text, it will shift the position by 20 characters. (in my test, this was not exactly the case, as it seems to have been the 18th empty line instead, but it is still plausible because counting the empty lines is nothing to be 100% sure about. See the next paragraph for an explanation of the "missing 3".)

####

There is even a possible explanation for the "missing" 3 empty lines adding up to the needed 20 as follows:

You have pasted directly at the last line before the "1. As of January 8" line in the picture. Mind that in edit mode, there are actually 3 empty lines for each empty line you see in the picture.
Then, there are exactly 17 empty lines before your Insertion (I checked this thoroughly), which is unequal to the actual shift by 20 characters. But perhaps there is something else before that counts like 3 empty lines, and that is probably the empty line that you can see after the end of the list (see the green "?" in the picture below).

Using the sandbox as an example again, final view, a green stripe means a shift by 3, the question mark should also mean a shift by 3:

[image]

If you clicked on edit, you would see that there is no 3-empty-lines-block where the green "?" is, although you would have expected it from the final view.

**That would mean that every empty line in the *final view* means a shift by 3**, while the editor view might "oversee" some empty lines.

####

As the empty lines are formatted like three visible lines first and then jump back to one line as soon as I have made the first change in the editor, there is somthing strange about them anyway, which makes the whole idea even more plausible.

Comment: No repro. Firefox 77.0.1 (64 bit)

Comment: Not reproducible on Firefox Nightly 80.0a1, not even in posts containing characters comprised of UTF-16 surrogate pairs (which often causes such index discrepancies). What browser are you using?

Comment: I have added the browser information in the question, thank you for testing. I have this bug since long, as far as I can remember it has been there since the 4 months that I am using SO on this laptop.

Comment: I wasn't able to duplicate this on my Mac. I'll have access to a Windows machine later (today hopefully) and see if I can reproduce in Edge. Also, anyone should feel free to edit my answer in an attempt to reproduce.

Comment: Hmm, I wasn't able to reproduce with Microsoft Edge 44.17763.831.0 using Microsoft EdgeHTML 18.17763. Are you using any extensions?

Comment: @ BSMP I am not using any extensions.

Comment: Repro with no extensions Win 10 64 bit 2004 19041.329, Microsoft Edge 44.19041.1.0, no repro in FF

Comment: @Nick, would you mind trying this again on your repro case, and just check now if pasting a picture somewhere in the middle of an edited text is shifted as well, and then confirm on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399646/edit-whatever-paste-a-picture-somewhere-and-it-will-be-inserted-slightly-too-l/399647#399647?

Comment: No repro, now with a new computer. Windows 10 Home 10.0.19041 Build 19041 64bit, Edge Version 84.0.522.44 (64-Bit), Bold text appears exactly for the marked selection.