# How to report a bug in a question?

Tags: support, editor, bug-reporting-process

When I find a bug in the SO editor, how would I inform about it?

Because it is not a question, just a bug report, like an issue on github. I simply want to reach the development team and the members that try to reproduce the error in the comments.

It is no question and thus there is no actual answer possible.

Context:

I added an idea that could explain the bug in a separate answer, and the documentation of this in another long answer, and this was deleted and the “question“ was closed because it needs more clarification, not because it is not reproducible. I guess that I need to state a question that can be answered? Which is not needed in this case.
One similar case is still open at [format bug: edit > mark a text > click on **B** for bold or *I* for italic > start of the format change is slightly too late](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399155/format-bug-edit-mark-a-text-click-on-b-for-bold-or-i-for-italic-sta/399653#399653) as an example of what I meant.

Comment: Just post it here and tag with [meta-tag:bug]. Make sure you describe the problem very precisely and show steps to reproduce

Comment: Please ensure you include the browser (and version) and OS (and version) you are using when encountering the bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Meta is the correct place to post bug reports. Use the tag [bug](/questions/tagged/bug).

The reason why your previous bug report was closed is because it was not clear or understandable to the community. The closure had nothing to do with the fact that it was inappropriately posted or off-topic.

The answers to a bug report are confirmation that the bug has been reproduced by someone else and a description of the root cause, and/or a post from a developer saying that it has been fixed, in which version, and how. You should not continue to add additional information to your bug report by posting answers. Instead, edit the question.