# Unable to post updated answer

Tags: bug, status-norepro, error-message

I faced the following error while trying to post an update to my existing answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/63253721/10819573:

[image]

Not being sure where to report this bug, my first attempt was to report to Stack Overflow support. However, on submitting the issue, I got the following message:

[image]

Then, I found [this helpful answer by Cody Gray](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/399704/10819573) and I am posting the problem here.

Comment: Whenever I encountered that error (no indication on something specifically wrong with the edit), it was usually just a temporary connection error and clicking again on *Save Edits* worked...

Comment: @Tomerikoo - I tried this option. I tried even in a different browser but nothing worked. For sure, this is a bug. In fact, I wanted to post the content of the answer in this question as well but here also I got the error: An error occurred submitting the edit. It looks like there is only way to submit the content to the Stack Overflow team is via the email.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/contact/submit is not a correct contact page https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVuKt.jpg it will be https://stackoverflow.com/contact

Comment: @sta - If you click the `Contact Us` at the bottom of this page, you will be redirected the page where I first tried to report the problem. Once you submit the form, the address in the browser will become stackoverflow.com/contact/submit

Comment: I see you added some links in the edit. This is just a guess, but if the same edit raises the same error here, maybe it's something about the system blocking the links... Try to submit the edit without the links themselves and see if it works

Comment: Yeah, same as what @Tomerikoo says, I recall problems with Oracle links as well, those `[3]` and `[4]` links could be the culprit.

Comment: I have tried all options. My network blocks Pastebin, so I have put the content at [ideone](https://ideone.com/i4qEsL). Is anyone able to edit my answer and post the content?

Comment: @Live and Let Live I just I tried and submitted successfully

Comment: @sta - Where did you post? My answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/63253721/10819573 is still the same. I requested to post the content from [ideone editor](https://ideone.com/i4qEsL) to https://stackoverflow.com/a/63253721/10819573

Comment: I talked only about http://stackoverflow.com/contact/submit

Comment: @sta - It's another confirmation that there is indeed some bug because of which Stack Overflow support form too showed the Technical Difficulty page. I had put the content of my answer in the support form and probably there is something in the content which Stack Overflow forms are not able to handle. The content is available in the [ideone editor](https://ideone.com/i4qEsL) for Stack Overflow developers to investigate the issue.

Comment: @LiveandLetLive The content at ideone is wrong, as it invalidates URLs, so it wouldn't be possible for people looking at that content to investigate

Comment: That said, I could post the edit fine after manually adjusting the links based on your screenshot here

Comment: Thanks, @Nick for posting the update. Much appreciated! What did you adjust in the content?

Comment: @LiveandLetLive Domains on ideone are replaced with `https://<first char of domain>...content-available-to-author-only...<end of domain>/` (see [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMYNC.png)), I copied the content and just replaced the domains with what they were meant to be based on your screenshot, so in theory... i didn't modify the content you were trying to submit

Comment: @Nick - Surprising! Let me try to edit the answer you just posted. I'll update here if I face any issue again.

Comment: @Nick - It looks like there is some problem with my user Id. I just tried to put a comma in the answer you just posted, and I got the same error. Any idea where to contact? Not sure, if it is [Stack Overflow support](https://stackoverflow.com/company/contact).

Comment: I'll ask around, if you can't use support here is probably the best place to get attention

Comment: Thanks, @Nick for helping me out. I've just reported this issue to Stack Overflow support and this time I was able to submit the issue. As soon as I get a response, I'll update here.

Comment: @Nick - I did not get any response from Stack Overflow support team. In the support ticket, I had also put the link to this question so that the team could understand the problem better. As of now, I am still not able to submit any edit in my answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/63253721/10819573 and am still getting the same error. I am able to do everything else (submit a new answer, edit other answers etc.) but submit any edit in the answer in this question. Though you helped to post the update, still I want the SO dev team to look into the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a generic error message that is not ever sent from our server. It is directly in the client-side code to handle the "could not connect to the server" issue. Based on your screenshot, you are experiencing connectivity issues and the save failed simply because a connection could not make it through to us.

That also means there isn't anything we can do. It is not an issue with us.

Comment: Hi animuson♦ - Thanks for the answer. Why is it happening with this particular answer? In fact, when I put the content of the answer into the support ticket, even the ticket could not be raised. What is that I was not able to submit it but Nick (kindly) could submit it?

Comment: If it's only occurring there, possibly something on your network is blocking the request based on text within the request. Would not be the first time it's happened. We see it a lot with people trying to submit SQL queries on corporate connections.

Comment: Oh...Ok...Got it...maybe because of my VPN connection to my corporate network...Thank you.